Issue Integrating OGCFrontController with Spring Boot 3.4.0 and Configuring WFS/WMS in deegree 3.6.0-pre2
I am working with the latest version of deegree (3.6.0-pre2) and attempting to integrate the OGCFrontController into a Spring Boot 3.4.0 project. My goal is to configure WFS and WMS services, ideally with support for AIXM.
Unfortunately, I have not found any comprehensive documentation or examples to guide me through this integration. The project structure is complex, and I am struggling to make progress.
Here is the relevant configuration snippet from my code:
@Bean  
public ServletRegistrationBean<OGCFrontController> servletRegistrationBean() {  
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new OGCFrontController(), "/ogc/*");  
}  

When I send a request to http://localhost:8080/ogc/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities, I receive the following response:
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd" version="1.1.0">  
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NotFound">  
    <ows:ExceptionText>No service with identifier 'wfs' available.</ows:ExceptionText>  
  </ows:Exception>  
</ows:ExceptionReport>  

Additionally, the logs contain these errors:
2024-12-05T22:34:09.496 ERROR [...] DefaultWorkspace: Unable to build resource OWSProvider:wfs: OGCFrontController has not been initialized yet.  
2024-12-05T22:34:09.489 WARN [...] StoredQueryHandler: Managed stored query directory does not exist. CreateStoredQuery/DropStoredQuery requests cannot be processed.

I suspect the issue might be related to the deegree workspace or its initialization. I am not certain how to properly configure and activate the necessary components for this setup.
Any guidance or examples to resolve this?
